# How to change position of items within an array?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function that changes positions of the items inside an array.

For example, I have this array:

[1, 2, 3] - if I call the function I get this => [2, 3, 1];
If I call the function again I should have this => [3, 1, 2];
The next time it should move again and so on.
But instead, if I call the function a second time I get this again => [2, 3, 1];

How could I make this work properly?

I know why this is happening, every time I call the function it receives the same values in the same order, I get that, that's why I built another array (move) to receive the values in the current order, it was an attempt to use this new array the second time I call the function, I tried it using an if/else statemente, but it didn't work; I also built another function passing 'move' as a parameter, and it worked, but just doesn't make any sense I have to have a different function for every move.

p.s. I am receiving the values from a HTML input.

```
<input id="numero1" value="">
<button onclick="moveLeft()">Move</button>


var n1 = document.getElementById("numero1");

function moveLeft() {
    var str = n1.value;
    var arr = str.split('');
    var move = [];
    
    console.log(arr);
    arr.splice(0, 3, arr[1], arr[2], arr[0]);
    console.log(arr);

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        move.push(arr[i]);
    }

    console.log(move);
    teste(move);
}


function teste(move) {
    console.log(move);
    move.splice(0, 3, move[1], move[2], move[0]);
    console.log(move);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to sort the array? Or move one item in the array to a specific spot in the array?

Comment: I am trying to move 1 position to the left every time I call the function

Comment: Okay. So basically take the first item in the array and put it at the end of the array so everything moves one spot to the left? If so, then the answer by @ZER0 is spot on.

Comment: Yes, I did that. But I am always getting the same result because the function is always running with the same values. In his case it works, but I need to call the function from a button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood properly, I think you can simplify in one line function:

```
const moveLeft = (arr) => arr.push(a.shift());
```

Notice that this function would mutate the content of the array but I guess that what you want:

```
const array = [1, 2, 3];

moveLeft(array);
console.log(array)// [2, 3, 1]

moveLeft(array);
console.log(array)// [3, 1, 2]

moveLeft(array);
console.log(array)// [1, 2, 3]
```

Basically with [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) we add a new element at the end of the array, and the new element we add, is the return value of the method [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift), that removes the first element from an array and return it.

**Edit**

If you don't want to mutate the original array, the fastest way is create a shallow copy and pass that to the function:

```
 const newArray = array.slice();
 moveLeft(newArray);

 console.log(newArray, array) // [2, 1, 3] [1, 2, 3]
```

However, a possible implementation that always return a new array, could be:

```
 const moveLeft = (arr) => [...arr.slice(1), arr[0]]
```

Just for future reference. But keep in mind that here you're create a shallow copy, (so one new array) and returns a new array from the spread operator, so it's less ideal. It could be useful only if you're writing an API that never allow mutability.

**Edit 2**

As per comment, the `input`'s value should reflect the new order, so, given the `moveLeft` function written before (the first one, that mutates the content):

```
<input id="numero1" value="">
<button onclick="inputMoveLeft('numero1')">Move</button>
```

And the JS:

```
function inputMoveLeft(id) {
  const input = document.getElementById(id);

 input.value = moveLeft(input.value.split("")).join("");
}
```

It should give you the result you were looking for.

Comment: Yes, it could work, but the problem is that I am calling this function from a button, so, everytime I call it, it receives the same values coming from the input and the process is repeated. If I would able to stop this process and use the values save into the array 'move', I guess I could make it work, but I don't know how. In your example it works properly, because the current value is saved in 'array', but that is exactly what I am not being able to do inside a function.

Comment: I apologize, I am not sure if I am being clear, I am still in programming and don't know how to express myself clearly when asking questions.

Comment: Ah, I see. You can either update the value in the button, or store it somewhere. What do you prefer? The first one would be visible to the user.

Comment: The first one, use the button. I guess it would make things more clear to me.

Comment: I just tried it and worked great. Thank you very much for your patience. It was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

pop and shift sound like the thing you need:

```
function rotateLeft(array){
    let first = array.shift()
    array.push(first); // add to end
    return array;
}

function rotateRight(array){
    let last = array.pop()
    array.unshift(last); // add to front
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Hello. Yes, but in this case I would have the same problem. If I call the functino a second time I would get the same result the first because the values storage inside would be the same. What I really need is storage the result of the process, and I could apply the method on this.